# Is a closure variable not created if not used?

Tags: javascript, closures, google-chrome-devtools

In [this example](https://codesandbox.io/s/q8y7q0km1q), Google Chrome Devtools won't find variable "y" in closure scope, but it will show "x".

My guess is that "y" won't appear because it's not used.

Am I right?

[image]

Comment: I'd think the variable *is* created, but after `outer` runs, it can't be referenced anymore, so it gets GC'd, though maybe smart compilers would see that `y` is never used and not bother assigning it. Might be engine-dependent.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's engine dependent.

On Google Chrome (Version 70.0.3538.77 (Official Build) (64-bit)), I can't see "y" variable:

[image: Chrome]

However on Firefox variable "y" is accessible:

[image: Firefox]

I'm not sure how these engines work, I assume Chrome during compile time have a look at variable "y" and says "hey it's not used in this scope, we don't need it". Whereas Firefox includes it.